# Converting a generic Iterator (e.g. SkipWhile) back to a specialised iterator (e.g. std::path::Components)

Tags: rust, path, iterator, type-conversion

To avoid the XY problem, here's what I originally want to do:
I have a path: `/foo/bar/bloo/baz/file.txt` and would like the most efficient way to obtain `bloo/baz/file.txt` from that, essentially skipping all ancestors before a specific component (in this case "bloo"). The approach that seemed most sensible to me was  to use the [components](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.components) function in std::path::Path.

My attempt looks like this:

```rust
let new_path = path
    .components()
    .skip_while(|v| if let Normal(v) = v { v.as_bytes() != b"bloo" } else { true })
    .skip(1)
    .as_path();
```

However this produces the following error:

```rust
error[E0599]: no method named `as_path` found for struct `Skip` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:712:14
    |
712 |             .as_path();
    |              ^^^^^^^ method not found in `Skip<SkipWhile<Components<'_>, [closure@src/main.rs:710:25: 710:89]>>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
error: could not compile `bloggers` due to previous error
```

Which is pretty self explanatory. I could just collect the remaining components into a string using the underlying filesystem separator, but that seems like more of a workaround than the actual solution.

In a more general sense: Can we convert a generic iterator such as `Skip` or `Map` back to a specialised iterator such as `Components`, `DirEntry`, etc. as long as we can guarantee that the Item type is the same?

edit#1:
For reference, the most efficient solution I could think of to build a new path from a string looks as follows (using the unstable `intersperse` and `MAIN_SEPARATOR_STR` features):

```rust
let new_path: String = path
    .components()
    .skip_while(|v| if let Normal(v) = v { v.as_bytes() != b"bloo" } else { true })
    .skip(1)
    .map(|v| v.as_os_str().to_str())
    .intersperse(Some(std::path::MAIN_SEPARATOR_STR))
    .collect::<Option<_>>()
    .ok_or_else(|| /* error reporting of choice */)?;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to consume the iterator eagerly:

```rust
let mut new_path = path.components();
while let Some(v) = new_path.next() {
    if let Normal(v) = v {
        if v.as_bytes() == b"bloo" { // Can be just `v == "bloo"`
            break;
        }
    }
}
let new_path = new_path.as_path();
```

`itertools` has the [`dropping()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.dropping) method for an eager `skip()`, but doesn't have an eager equivalent to `skip_while()`, unfortunately, so you have to roll your own, like I did.

Comment: That's a fair solution as well. I assume that means there is no sensible way to convert back to a `Components` iterator?

Comment: `new_path` is already a `Components` iterator (to be honest, I'm not sure I got the mapping between the callbacks and the loop well, it's hard to figure out without running it).

Comment: Now I got it :P